# Where did you go? vs Where were you go?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, difference, past-tense, indian-english

In these following sentences, which one is grammatically correct?

> 1. Where did you go?
> 2. Where were you go?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"**Where did you go?**" is grammatically correct.

To improve the second one, you could say "**Where had you gone?**" or "**Where were you gone?**"

Comment: Even "Where were you gone?" sounds off to me. I'd just stick to the first one personally.

Comment: If you want to rephrase the second sentence in that sense, it should be *Where have you gone?*

Comment: @JasonBassford But that changes the tense of the sentence.

Comment: @BellaSwan It's still in the past tense and means roughly the same thing. *Where were you gone?* is unidiomatic, verging on ungrammatical. I certainly wouldn't recommend anybody say it. (Even *Where had you gone?* would be preferable.)